# MeteorJS and Coffeescript: "unexpected . "

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript, npm

I'm trying to use the `Email.send()` functionality within the Meteor email bundle and I am running into a small snag. I am trying to run this:

```
Email.send
({
    from: 'hello@email.net',
    to: 'someone@somewhere.info',
    subject: 'myapp: wowowowo!',
    text: 'Hello!'
})
```

Meteor returns this error:

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Errors prevented startup:                  

   While building the application:
   <runJavaScript-31>:148:11: server/server.coffee:162: unexpected .
   (compiling server/server.coffee) (at handler)

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
=> Started MongoDB.
```

Line 162 is the above call to the send function. Yes, I have already run `meteor add email`. What do I do? I need a fresh pair of eyes, thank you!

Comment: Copy paste your code in "Try coffeescript" at http://coffeescript.org/ and you'll see your mistake.

Comment: However, I don't think the code you've shown us should produce the error message you got. Sure the error isn't is somewhere else?

Comment: @PeppeL-G: I've tried the module without the call to send email and it works just fine, so I can't think that it's anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that another team member of mine was editing the file and his text editor inserted tabs instead of spaces! I converted all the indents to be space delimited and it then worked.

Answer (score 2):

Using js2coffee.org, you might want to try this:

```
Email.send
  from: "hello@email.net"
  to: "someone@somewhere.info"
  subject: "myapp: wowowowo!"
  text: "Hello!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert the code into http://js2coffee.org/ and you will see what JavaScript it generates.

You could write it like this

```
Email.send
  from: 'hello@email.net',
  to: 'someone@somewhere.info',
  subject: 'myapp: wowowowo!',
  text: 'Hello!'
```

But I prefer this:

```
Email.send(
  from: 'hello@email.net',
  to: 'someone@somewhere.info',
  subject: 'myapp: wowowowo!',
  text: 'Hello!'
)
```

or this:

```
Email.send({
  from: 'hello@email.net',
  to: 'someone@somewhere.info',
  subject: 'myapp: wowowowo!',
  text: 'Hello!'
})
```

It's more clear that it's a function that takes an object as a parameter.

BTW every time you are not sure what CoffeeScript code does, use http://js2coffee.org/ to find it out.

Comment: Hmm... You don't like coffeescript at all, do you? Your last suggestion is identical to the corresponding JavaScript code. The point with coffeescript is to write short codes, I would go with Chip Castles suggestion.

Comment: @PeppeL-G: There's nothing wrong with including the parentheses if you think they make the code easier to read, I include them pretty much all the time (in both CoffeeScript and Ruby). And there's nothing wrong with including various options in an answer, I'd even say that that's to be encouraged.